# Who did the stunts in The Greatest American Hero?

Tags: stunts, the-greatest-american-hero

Did William Katt do his own stunts in The Greatest American Hero? Or was it a stuntman?

Comment: Given the number of stuntmen involved it seems unlikely - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081871/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

William Katt's stunt double was [Dennis Madalone](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0534480/).

https://www.youtube.com/user/dennismadalone